# SSH running slow on cygwin

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I have a Windows XP box with Cygwin running and the SSH service.  I'd like to use PuTTY to connect to it from other computers on the local network.  PuTTY works fine and I actually get a relatively speedy login prompt.  But anytime I do an 'ls' on the root directory ('/') it typically doesn't complete, like the command is hung.  Other PuTTY sessions suffer as well, no matter what i'm doing (even just an 'ls' on my home directory might take awhile or not finish).  It is like a deadlock occurred somewhere in the ssh/cygwin system.

The root directory does contain the 'cygdrive' folder which is the contents of the host computer.  Could this be causing the slowdown?

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour in native cygwin sessions on the Windows XP box?

Comment: @EightBitTony Fairly certain I don't see that but i'd have to check.  Which I can't do until later today.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be related to network shares located in the structure of cygdrive...

Comment: Does is the issue go away if you disable on-demand virus scanning on the XP box (assuming it's turned on)

Comment: It is looking like a network share that was unavailable was causing the ls command to grind to a halt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue was most certainly a network share that was unavailable.  Basically the computer SSH was being hosted on talks to my wife's computer's shared directories.  Well, her computer wasn't available (sleeping I believe) and it really hosed up Cygwin.

When I woke her computer up, everything started zooming again.  I am confident that cygwin was unable to stat the network share and caused the slowdown.

If anyone has a better write up, I'll gladly accept that as an answer.